# How to add a parameter to a search URL when the user clicks the submit button?

Tags: jquery, shopify

This is what I tried, but on multiple submits the value string in the URL is not updating, so the user is still seeing the previous search results' URL. The search functionality (built on Shopify) works fine without the added parameters. Any ideas what went wrong?

The form:

```
<form id="search" method='get' action="/search">
  <input id="search_text" name="q" class="field" type="text" value="{{ search.terms | remove: ' AND -vendor:Archive AND -tag:Insurance' }}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="type" value="product">
  <input id="search_submit" type="submit" border="0" value="Search" alt="Submit Search"/>
</form>
```

My function:

```
$('#search input[type="submit"]').click(function(e){
  var excludedCats = ' AND -vendor:Archive AND -tag:Insurance&type=product';
  var new_val = $('#search input[name="q"]').val();
  e.preventDefault();
  location.href = '/search?q=' + new_val + excludedCats;
});

$('.field, textarea').focus(function() {
  if(this.title==this.value) {
    this.value = '';
  }
}).blur(function(){
  if(this.value=='') {
    this.value = this.title;
  }
});
```

Comment: Why dont you add method="get" to your form element and remove the javascript?

Comment: Try encoding the search value `encodeURIComponent(new_val + excludedCats)`. Also, better bind to the form event `$('#search').on('submit', function(e) { ... });`.

Comment: thank you, tried but it did not fix the issue.